# Is the distance function in a metric space (uniformly) continuous?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Is the function $x\mapsto d(x, z)$ continuous? Is it uniformly continuous?

Comment: If you are asking whether the distance function $d:X\times X\to\mathbb R$ is continuous when $(X,d)$ is a metric space, then aswer is yes. You *should* try to prove it yourself; first do it for $\mathbb R$ with its usual metric, and then generalize.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I was also trying the same question. But how to prove it using $\epsilon - \delta$ notation.Let $(x,y) \in X$ and $(x',y') \in X$ then whenever $||(x,y)-(x',y')|| \lt \delta$ then we have $|d(x,y)-d(x',y')| \lt \epsilon$.. right?? How to go ahead with this proof

Answer (score 50, accepted):

As Qiaochu points out $d(x,y)$ is continuous for fixed $x$. You may like to see this as well, as this is a familiar result in Topology:

> If $A$ is a non empty subset of a metric space $(X,d)$ then the function $f$ on $X$ given by 
>   $$f(x)=d(x,A):= \inf_{y\in A} d(x, y)$$ 
>   is continuous. Indeed, 
>   $$| f(x) - f(y) | = | d(x,A) - d(y,A) | \leq d(x,y),$$
>   and thus $f$ is uniformly continuous (use $\delta = \epsilon$ in any point).

To show this, let $x$ and $y$ be points in $X$, and $p$ any point in $A$.

Then 
$$d(x,p) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,p)\ \ \ \ \text{ (triangle inequality)}$$
and so 
$$d(x,A) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,p)$$ 
as $d(x,A)$ is the infimum. But then $d(y,p) \geq d(x,A) - d(x,y)$ (for all $p$, obtained by subtracting from the previous inequality), so that $d(y,A) \geq d(x,A) - d(x,y)$ (as $d(y,A)$ is the infimum).
So : $d(x,A) - d(y,A) \leq d(x,y)$.

Now reverse the roles of $x$ and $y$ to get
$d(y,A) - d(x,A) \leq d(x,y)$.

This is taken from http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=homework_help_2004;task=show_msg;msg=1323.0001

Comment: where did you use the fact that A is closed?

Comment: Why are we assuming that the metric on $\mathbb{R}$ is the standard one?

Comment: @GAJO I think $d(x,E)$ is continuous in $x$ for any nonempty subset $E$.

Answer (score 10):

Yes.  The standard definition of the topology induced by a metric ensures this; in fact it's not hard to see that it's the coarsest topology such that $d(x, y)$ is continuous for fixed $x$.

Comment: Isn't it also the coarsest one for which $d$ itself is continuous?

Comment: You use $|d(z,x_n)-d(z,x)|\le d(x_n,x)\le\epsilon$ by the reverse triangular inequality?