# a multiple choice question on metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$  be a metric space and let $A \subset X$. For $x \in X$ define  $$d(x,A) = \inf\{d(x, y) \mid y \in A\}.$$
Pick out the true statements:

a. $x \mapsto d(x,A)$ is a uniformly continuous function.

b. If $\operatorname{del} A = \{x \in X \mid d(x,A) = 0\} ∩ \{x\in X \mid d(x,X\setminus A) = 0\}$, then $\operatorname{del} A$ is closed for any $A \subset X$.

c. Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $X$ and define $d(A,B)  = \inf\{d(a,B) \mid a \in A\}$. Then $d(A,B) = d(B,A)$.

I know that (a) is true but no idea about the others. Thanks for your help.

Comment: in c) you just use the fact that you can swap the order of $\inf$

Comment: del (A) = closure(A) \ closure (X-A)

Comment: in b> is the question $\operatorname{del} A = \{x \in X \mid d(x,A) = 0\} \setminus \{x\in X \mid d(x,X\setminus A) = 0\}$ or is it $\operatorname{del} A = \{x \in X \mid d(x,A) = 0\} \cap\{x\in X \mid d(x,X\setminus A) = 0\}$

Comment: sorry for my mistake. you are right. I  have corrcted my fault

Comment: For a see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/8068/8297).

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be closed, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?).

Answer (score 1):

b>
$\operatorname{del}(A) = \overline{{A}} \cap \overline{{X-A}}$ = boundary(A) and boundary(A) is always closed