# Is the following function uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

I am supposed to prove if the function
$ f:X \to \mathbb {R}, f (x) = dist (x, A)$
where $ A$ is an arbitrary subset o the metric space $X $ is uniformly continuous.

If  both points $ x $ and $ y $ are in the closure of $ A$ this is true since since the distance is constant 0 and is uniformly continuous.

If $ x \in \overline{A}$ and $ y \in \overline{A}^{c}$ then for $|dist (y, A)|<\epsilon$ we can take $\delta=\epsilon$ and it is again uniformly continuous.

However when both point are outside of $A$,  I'm not sure of what to do. I started by defining $dist (x, A) = inf dist(x, a), $for $  a \in A$, but I haven't been able to bound the distance between the points in terms of this.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/is-the-function-distance-continuous

Comment: Thank you! It was very simple...