# Prove that if $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$ for every continuous real-valued function in the metric space M, $x_n \rightarrow x$ on M.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

The problem goes like: Suppose that we are given a point $x$ and a sequence $x_n$ in a metric space $M$, and suppose that  $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$ for every continuous real-valued function $f$ on $M$. Prove that $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $M$.

I was thinking that since the $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$ for EVERY $f$, then we can find one with a continuous inverse (could it just be $f(x) = x$?). Then since both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous and also $f$ is bijective, it is a homeomorphism. Therefore, the preimage converges based on the fact that $f$ being a homeomorphism. Is this correct?

Comment: We can't generally find a continuous $f$ with continuous inverse. If e.g. $M = \mathbb{Q}$, every continuous function $\mathbb{R}\to M$ is constant.

Comment: The argument you proposed is not correct because $f(x)=x$ does not define a *real-valued* function and, more generally, there might not be any bijection between $M$ and the real line.  I suggest defining $f$ by $f(z)=d(x,z)$, where $d$ is the given metric of $M$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$M$ is a metric space. Therefore it has a distance function, $d$, [which is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8066/221811) if we fix one variable. Hence
$$ d_x(y) := d(x,y) $$
is a continuous function in $y$. But then $d_x(x)=0$, and $x_n \to x$ iff $d_x(x_n) \to 0$.