# (Uniform) continuity of function in metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Consider the metric space $(X,d)$ and the non-empty subset $A \subseteq X$. What can we say about the (uniform) continuity of the function $d_{A}: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto d_{A}(x) = \inf \{ d(a,x) | a \in A \}$? Should I make a case study on whether X is compact or not? Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: A google search for "metric uniform continuous" led this (see the first answer): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/is-the-distance-function-in-a-metric-space-uniformly-continuous

Comment: @ThePortakal see also the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

For $x,y \in X $ and $a\in A $, we have

$$d (a,x)\le d (a,y)+d (x,y) $$
$$\implies d_A (x)\le d (a,y)+d (x,y) $$
$$\implies d_A (x)-d (x,y)\le d (a,y) $$

$$\implies d_A (x)-d (x,y)\le d_A (y) $$
$$\implies d_A (x)-d_A (y)\le d (x,y) $$
and by symetry,
$$d_A (y)-d_A (x)\le d (x,y) $$

and finally
$$|d_A (x)-d_A (y)|\le d (x,y) $$
which proves that $x\mapsto d_A (x) $ is Lipschitz and uniformly continuous at $X $.