# Show the Euclidian projection onto a closed set is a Lipschitz function

Tags: projection

Let $f(x)=\min_{y \in C}\|y-x\|$ where $C$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Show $f(x)$ is a Lipschitz function with constant $L=1$.

**My try**

I need to show
$$
|f(x_2)-f(x_1)| \leq \|x_2-x_1\| \quad \forall x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n
$$

When $x_1,x_2 \in C$, it is trivial because $f(x_2)=f(x_1)=0$. When one of them is in $C$, let's say $x_1$, then $f(x_1)=0$ and $|f(x_2)-f(x_1)|=\min_{y \in C}\|y-x_2\|\leq \|x_1-x_2\|$ because $x_1 \in C$.

**Question**

How can I show it when neither $x_1$ nor $x_2$ is in $C$?

Comment: It is not even well defined. You probably forgot to assume convexity of $C$.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan: It is well-defined. Then projection vector is not unique but the projection error value for a given point $x$ is well-defined.

Comment: @MoisheKohan If $C\ne\emptyset$, then $f$ is well-defined: let $y_0\in C$. Then $\inf_{y\in C} \lVert x-y\rVert=\inf_{y\in \{z\in C\,:\, \lVert z-x\rVert\le\lVert y_0-x\rVert\}} \lVert y-x\rVert$. Since $\{z\in C\,:\, \lVert z-x\rVert\le\lVert y_0-x\rVert\}$ is compact, that $\inf$ is achieved. If it had $\inf$ instead of $\min$, then it would also be defined in all metric spaces, and for all non-empty subsets.

Comment: In a more general setting we have: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8068/470072

Comment: @Sudix: Very good point. How can I tailor that proof for my question. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: The minimum exists but need not be unique. That's why the map is not well defined. You have to invoke the axiom of choice to choose the projection. This map will not even be continuous.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan: what do you mean? There might be multiple $y$'s but all of them have the same function value otherwise we get a contradiction.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am tailoring the general solution posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/is-the-distance-function-in-a-metric-space-uniformly-continuous?noredirect=1&lq=1) to answer your question:

Let $z \in C$ and $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be arbitrary points. Using triangle inequality you can write the following:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\|z-x_1\|
&\leq \|z-x_2\|+\|x_2-x_1\|
\\
\min_{y \in C}\|y-x_1\|\leq
\|z-x_1\|
&\leq \|z-x_2\|+\|x_2-x_1\|
\\
\min_{y \in C}\|y-x_1\|
&\leq \min_{y \in C} \|y-x_2\|+\|x_2-x_1\|
\end{aligned}
$$
where in the second line we know that $\min_{y \in C}\|y-x_1\|\leq
\|z-x_1\|$ because $z \in C$, and in the third line we know that $z$ is an arbitrary point so we can let it be a minimizer of $\|y-x_2\|$ over $C$ to achieve $\min_{y \in C} \|y-x_2\|$. Thus we have
$$
\min_{y \in C}\|y-x_1\|
- \min_{y \in C} \|y-x_2\|
\leq \|x_2-x_1\|
\tag{1}.
$$
Switch $x_1$ and $x_2$ to get the following:
$$
\min_{y \in C}\|y-x_2\|
- \min_{y \in C} \|y-x_1\|
\leq \|x_2-x_1\|
\tag{2}.
$$
Put (1) and (2) together, then you get
$$
\Big| \min_{y \in C}\|y-x_2\|
- \min_{y \in C} \|y-x_1\|
\Big|
\leq \|x_2-x_1\|
$$
which means $|f(x_2)-f(x_1)| \leq \|x_2-x_1\|$.