# Show the error squared of the Euclidian projection onto a closed set is a continuous function

Tags: continuity, lipschitz-functions, projection

I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4749873/show-the-euclidian-projection-onto-a-closed-set-is-a-lipschitz-function) and now I am wondering if the previous proof can be used to show the following:

Let $f(x)=\min_{y \in C}\|y-x\|^2$ where $C$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Show $f(x)$ is a continuous function.

Answer (score 1):

Counter-example: $C=\{0\}$ in $\mathbb R$. In this case $f(x)=x^{2}$ which is not Lipschitz (since $f'(x)=2x$ is not bounded).

Answer for the modified question: $f(x)=[g(x)]^{2}$ where $g(x)=\min_{y \in C} \|y-x\|$. By the link you have provided, $g$ is continuous. Hence, $f$ is also continuous.

Comment: What if I add the condition of $0 \in C$?

Comment: I don't understand. Doesn't $0 \in\{0\}$? BTW, any one point set $C$ will also serve as a counter-example.

Comment: Never mind. I got confused. My goal is to show it is continuous that is why I tried to show it is Lipschitz. I will edit the question. Could you modify your answer.

Comment: @Sepide I have edited my answer.

Comment: $f(x)\neq (g(x))^2$ because $\min_{y\in C}\|y-x\|^2 \neq (\min_{y\in C}\|y-x\|)^2$.

Comment: @Sepide If $E$ is a set of non-negative real numbers then $\min \{x^{2}: x \in E\}=(\min \{x: x \in E\})^{2}$

Comment: Can you please prove this result for me or provide me with a source?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147785/discussion-between-geetha290krm-and-sepide).